# Filtering and adding GeoJSON features using function in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, function

I have a Leaflet map where I am adding the features from a GeoJSON file. I am able to filter the features depending on the properties in the GeoJSON.

I am writing out the same giant block of code each time I add a layer and just changing the variables. I leave off the `.addTo(map)` and load it later from the layerControl by clicking on a checkbox.

I wrote a function that filters and adds the layers. But it only works if I add it to the map on load -- `addTo(map)` inside the function. Which loads it with initial paint of the map. I want to add it later, using the checkboxes in the L.control.layers menu.

I've tried several different approaches, removing the `.addTo(map)` from the function and adding it to the end of the function call. I've also tried calling the function from within the `L.control.layers` group.  I left some comments in the snippet and some comments on what I have tried after the snippet. I may be going about this all wrong.

Here is what I have:

```
var grayscale = new L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ', maxZoom: 16 })
var mapOptions = {
     center: [44.2457, -116.9228],
     zoom: 14,
                 layers: [grayscale]
 }

var dog1 = new L.marker([44.2441, -116.9228]).bindPopup('This is just a placeholder.')

map = new L.Map("map", mapOptions);

// ========  function call
var fence2 = newFeature('red', 'fence')
//console.log(fence2) returns 'undefined' but it appears on the map?!
var dog = newFeature('red', 'dog')
// var dog4 = newFeature('blue', 'dog').addTo(map) // with .addTo(map) removed in the function -- nope!

// layercontrol
var baseMaps = {
"Grayscale": grayscale,
};
var overlayMaps = {
"new L.marker dog": dog1,
"not from function": groups.dogs,
"add function feature here after load": dog1   
};
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, { collapsed:false }).addTo(map);
function newFeature(eColor, group){
L.geoJson(myGeoJson, {
 filter: function(feature, layer) {
   return (feature.properties.farm === "Kerner" && feature.properties.group === group);
 },
 onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
 layer.bindPopup('farm: ' + feature.properties.farm + '<br />Notes: ' +                                    
feature.properties.description)},

style: function (feature) {
        return {
            color: eColor,
            weight: 3,
            opacity: 1,
            dashArray: 4
        }
  }
    // !!!only works if I add to map here inside the function
    // !!! adds the layer on load
  }).addTo(map)
  //})
  }
```

If I remove the `.addTo(map)` from the function and add it when I call the function:

```
var dog = newFeature('red', 'dog').addTo(map)
```

results in this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addTo')"
```

Even if the function generates a visible layer, if I add the var to a `L.control.layer` it breaks the layer control.

```
var overlayMaps = {

"kerner": fence2 //  the L.control disappears from the map.
 // console - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setZIndex')
```

All fine with

```
.addTo(map)
```

called like this:

```
var dog = newFeature('red', 'dog')
```

inside the function. But that is not the result I am looking for.

Here is a working, but not as needed,  [concept jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grantiago/9btdm0zy/)

and a sample of the geojson. No surprises there.

```
var myGeoJson = [{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -116.921847,
                    44.245915
                ],
                [
                    -116.921986,
                    44.245442
                ],
                [
                    -116.922721,
                    44.245423
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "Calf Pasture",
            "farm": "Kerner",
            "description": "pasture fence N end.",
            "group": "fence"
        }
    },{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -116.915847,
                    44.243915
                ],
                [
                    -116.915986,
                    44.243442
                ],
                [
                    -116.916721,
                    44.243423
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "Other Pasture",
            "farm": "Kerner",
            "description": "other pasture fence S end.",
            "group": "fence"
        }
    },{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": 
                [-116.9210, 44.2450]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "foodo",
            "farm": "Kerner",
            "description": "another dog yet.",
            "group": "dog"
        }
    }
    ]
    }];
```

Comment: @Cody Gray I don't unterstand why you have migrated this question to gis.stackexchange ... Do you want to migrate all [12000 leaflet questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leaflet) from stackoverflow to gis.stackexchange ?

Comment: @FalkeDesign this is where I intended to post it. Simple as that. Thank you.

Comment: @TomazicM gone.

Comment: The GIS Stack Exchange welcomes focused questions about Leaflet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just one small mistake in your code.

In the function `newFeature(eColor, group)` you are not returning created layer, so any use of the function result fails.

Code should look something like this:

```
function newFeature(eColor, group){
  var vectorLayer = L.geoJson(myGeoJson, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.farm === "Kerner" && feature.properties.group === group);
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup('farm: ' + feature.properties.farm + '<br />Notes: ' +                                    
      feature.properties.description)
    },
    style: function (feature) {
      return {
        color: eColor,
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 1,
        dashArray: 4
      }
    }
  });
  return(vectorLayer);  // added function return value
}

var dog = newFeature('red', 'dog').addTo(map);
var fence2 = newFeature('red', 'fence');

var overlayMaps = {
  "kerner": fence2
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
```